# Django: Search Engine

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make a search engine of sorts in Django, where the user enters a query via a form and gets an output if the query exists in the database. Here's my code:

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

from Search import views

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^', views.form),
url(r'^search/', views.data,name='search'),

]
```

models.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from abc import ABCMeta

from django.db import models


# Create your models here.


class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    album_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    album_logo = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.album_title + "-" + self.artist
```

views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse,Http404
from models import Album
from forms import FormQuery
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import loader
from . import *

def data(request):
   if request.method=='POST':
        form=FormQuery(request.POST)
        data=form.cleaned_data
        value=data['query']
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                album1 = Album.objects.get(artist__contains=value)

                return render(request,'Search/form.html',{'album':album1})
            except:
                raise Http404("Does not exist.")
    else:
        return render(request,'Search/form.html')
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class FormQuery(forms.Form):
    query=forms.CharField()
```

form.html:

```
<form action="{% url 'search' %}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}

  <fieldset>

    Enter an album:<br>
    <input type="text" name="query" ><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit for Search >>">
  </fieldset>

</form>
    {% if album %}
        <h1>{{ album }}</h1>
    {% endif %}
```

However, when I type the query, I see the url change ,but the page remains the same and my result(album name) is not displayed. I am new to Django.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint? you've made a form but then you ignore it completely in your template, its possible it has errors but then that should produce a different error since your view doesn't return a response

Comment: Please catch the exception like `except Album.DoesNotExist:` and add the `return` statement in `else`. Also you should expect more than just 1 result if you are doing `__contains`, try using `Album.objects.filter`

Comment: @Sayse Can you elaborate on how to use the form in the template?

Answer (score 0):

`form.is_valid()` must be called before accessing to `cleaned_data`.